# validation only working if all text inputs are blank, not any text input is blank

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to produce a validation message in an alert for when any text input within a question is empty. So for example if I have 2 blank text inputs for question 1, if both text inputs are blank, it displays the validation message `You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox`.

But the problem is that for question 1 for example, if 1 text input is blank but the other is not blank, it does not display the validation message, even though it should do as not all text inputs have been filled for question 1.

My question is that how can I get the validation message to appear if there is any blank text input per question?

Here is a fiddle so you can test it: http://jsfiddle.net/cbyJD/87/

Below is the validation() function code:

```
function validation() {

    // only keeping track of the final message
    var alertValidation = "",
        // toggle for showing only one error
        showOnlyOneError = true;

    $("input[data-type='qmark']").each(function(i) {  
        var questions = $(this).attr("data-qnum");
        var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + (i+1) + "_ans_text]").text()); 
        var txtinput = $(this).val(); 

        // the message for this question
        var msg = '';

        if (txtinput == '') {
            msg += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox \n";
        }

        if (marks < 0) {
            msg += "\n\u2022 Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n - You Need To Remove " + Math.abs(marks) +  " Marks";   
        } else if (marks > 0) {
            msg += "\n\u2022 Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n - You Have " + marks +  " Marks Remaining";   
        }

        // if there is an error for the question, add it to the main message
        if (msg.length) {
            alertValidation += alertValidation.length ? '\n\n' : '';
            alertValidation += "You have errors on Question Number: " + questions + "\n";
            alertValidation += msg;
            // stop if we only care about the first error
            return !showOnlyOneError;
        }
    });

    // show the error messages
    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you would have all your html in a javascript variable?  Seems extremely messy and hard to make sense of... Think of the guy (even if it is you) that has to maintain this down the road.

Comment: I agree with @blo0p3r you should certainly just use normal html and then hide the id or class. I've had to work with so much code like this and it's a nightmare. When this project gets larger, it will inevitably get messy. This is why people start to dislike javascript (other people, I love it).

Comment: It would help if you posted a sscce on jsfiddle. http://sscce.org http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Also, this is definitly controlled by some javascript?  If everything is pushed down by one line you have some sort of line break.  Good way to debug on your css : `* {border: 1px solid red}`.  Also, try changing your text that is posted... see what happens then?

Comment: for me whole function looks very overcomplex, why not setup the input with something like `<input class="validate" data-rules="int">`

Comment: I did it a complex way coz I needed to find suitable ids and question numbers and the best way I could do it was this complex way. Next time I will do it the way u stated

Comment: @Manixman Your validate function is stopping after the first error. If you fill in the first marks box and leave the second one empty, the error that gets reported is that there are less than 5 marks. Your function never gets to see that any of the other inputs are empty.

Comment: @skyline3000 Yes that is the problem but what is the solution for this to be fixed in code?

Comment: @Manixman do you always want a blank input to supersede all other errors? If there is just a single text input blank, say the last one, only that will be reported? Even if there are other errors? Or do you want blank text text input errors to mixed in with all of the other errors?

Comment: I want blank text input errors to be mixed with other errors. In other words I want alert to display all errors per question only. E.g If there are errors in question 1 and 3, I want it to first display an alert showing all errors in question 1 then when question 1 errros are fixed then when the user submits again then it shows all errors for question 3.

Comment: @skyline3000 here is an updated fiddle you can work with if you wish: http://jsfiddle.net/cbyJD/100/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a hidden variable `num_groups` with the total number of groups.

```
<p>
  <input type='hidden' id='num_groups' name='num_groups' value='2'>
  <input id="submitBtn" name="submitMarks" type="submit" value="Submit Marks" />
</p>
```

Second, change the `validate` function to work on a single group of questions:

```
function validation(group) {
  var msg = [];

  var nb = 0;     // Number of blank values
  $("input[data-qnum='" + group + "']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      nb++;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (nb != 0) {
    msg.push("\u2022 You have not entered in a value in all the Individual Marks textbox");
  }

  var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + group + "_ans_text]").text()); 
  if (marks != 0) {
    msg.push("\u2022 Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0");
    if (marks < 0) {
      msg.push("- You Need To Remove " + -marks + " Marks");
    } else if (marks > 0) {
      msg.push("- You Have " + marks + " Marks Remaining");
    }
  }

  if (msg.length > 0) {
    alert("You have errors on Question Number: " + group + "\n\n" + msg.join("\n"));
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Third, change the `myClickhandler` function to validate all the groups:

```
myClickHandler = function(e) {
  var ng = $('#num_groups').val();
  for (var group = 1; group <= ng; group++) {
    if (!validation(group)) return false;
  }
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Proceed?")) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "insertmarks.php",
      data: $("#markstbl").serialize(),
      async: false,
      type: "POST"
    });
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ePRM8/2/).

Comment: Hi, you're nearly there. When I tested fiddle and filled in one text input and left the other text input within the question empty, it still does not state in the alert that a text input is still empty. I upvoted your answer btw.

Comment: @Manixman Thank you for the feedback. I've update the fiddle since it was wrong. Let me know if now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `validation()` function returns `true` no matter what it finds.

You need to declare a variable at the top of this function called `errors` or similar, with a value of `false`. For everywhere in the function that an error is found, set the value of `errors` to `true`.

At the close of the function with...

```
return !errors; // return the value of errors NOT'ed
```

Then you call call `validation()` in a test, like so...

```
if (validation()) {
    // everything is groovy
} else {
    // make them do the form over, or something
}
```

Comment: I have not quite got the validation working in the fiddle. Can you look at the updated validation function and see where Im going wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/cbyJD/90/

Comment: Several problems: 1. `onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"` calls a function that you haven't defined. 2. You have extra `var` keywords at the beginning of `validation()`. 3. `parseInt($("[class*=q" + (i+1) + "_ans_text]").text());` references variable `i` that isn't declared (I think `i+1` should be `questions`.

Comment: The first two of those problems are reported by Chrome Developer Tools. Do you use this or Firebug?

Comment: @Barmar I tried to limit down the code, problem 1 isn't an issue in my full code as the function is there. Problem 2 and 3 I believe it fixed. For problem 3 I actually did forget to change it back to questions. Problem 2 sorted as well

Comment: Have you fixed the fiddle? These problems prevented it from working.

Comment: Fiddle is updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/cbyJD/100/ the errors you mentioned are fixed but the alert still not sorted yet